# Undefined when defined?

Tags: javascript, html

this is the html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script type='text/javascript' src="myScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>hi</p>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the javascript:

```
var buyButtons = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
console.log(buyButtons)
console.log(buyButtons[0])
```

the first console.log shows "*HTMLCollection []*", the second console.log showed "undefined", how is this even possible?

Ok, I read the other post, so I understand that the script should be below the DOM but **how did the first console.log work when it happens before the DOM?**

Please don't mark my question as duplicate, the other post did shows the solution but to this issue but it did not mention why would the first console.log work

Comment: `HTMLCollections` are *live* snapshots that change as the document changes.. (`querySelectorAll`, being static, works more intuitively)

Comment: @Andreas `buyButtons[0]` being undefined isn't strange at all, but I'm not 100% sure what OP's seeing / is confused about regarding the HTMLCollection

Comment: @Andreas Pretty sure OP understands that already, that's not what he's trying to fix

Comment: Although it’s a live collection and that could result in some surprising console behaviour, I wouldn’t count `HTMLCollection []` as part of that surprise. `[]` looks empty, right? What’s unexpected about its zeroth element being undefined?

Comment: Okay, marking as a duplicate with some confidence after seeing the “u need to click on it” comment on Kokodoko’s answer.

Comment: `elements = element.getElementsByTagName(tagName)` -> _"`elements` is a live `HTMLCollection` of found elements in the order they appear in the sub-tree. **If no elements were found, the HTMLCollection is empty.**"_ (Source: [Element.getElementsByTagName() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName))

Comment: i didn't know about this live collection thing..

Answer (score -1):

`console.log(buyButtons)` logs an empty array, because no dom elements were found

Comment: there are.. u need click on it

Comment: That's true, you can just do `document.getElementsByTagName("asdfghjkl");` It's still not going to be undefined, since it returns a list of elements with that tag-name, obviously no element are going to have that tag-name so the list is going to be empty

Comment: why are you talking about tag names?

Comment: Because you are using `getElementsByTagName`. Did you downvote because you don’t understand your own question?